# Converting ODataQuery to TableQuery to query Azure Table Storage using OData

Tags: c#, azure, odata, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm using Azure table storage and I'd like to be able to query using OData. I've come across the `Microsoft.Rest.Azure.OData.ODataQuery` class but I can't find any examples of how this is consumed.

The `CloudTable` object permits queries through a [`TableQuery<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery-1?view=azure-dotnet) object, so is there any way to convert an `ODataQuery` to a `TableQuery`?

I know that earlier versions of Azure's table storage used an underlying OData API but I don't know if this is still the case, and I haven't found any documentation detailing whether the table can be exposed through OData.

Can anyone explain how to query Azure table storage using OData - ideally through a library?

**EDIT:**
For clarity, I know that table storage exposes a REST API which accepts OData queries; what I'm looking for is a way to pass the OData query programmatically: If I have an `ODataQuery` object, how can I use this to query a `CloudTable` object?

Comment: could you please share your sample code on how to query Azure table Storage using OData (http request) in C#? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have any sample code - that is exactly what I was asking for in my OP.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone explain how to query Azure table storage using OData - ideally through a library?

We could get the answer from [Querying Tables and Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities). 
We also could get the C# demo code from the [Get started with Azure Table storage using .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet#retrieve-all-entities-in-a-partition)

> The Table service supports the following query options, which conform to the OData Protocol Specification. You can use these options to limit the set of tables, entities, or entity properties returned by a query.

[image]

**Update:**

If we use the fiddler to catch the library request, we could get that the library will constructthe OData query before send the request.

[image]

> That I'm looking for is a way to pass the OData query programmatically: If I have an ODataQuery object, how can I use this to query a CloudTable object?

Currently, Azure table storage doesn't fully support OData Protocol Specification.Based on my knowledge, it is not supported to use OdataQuery object directly.

You could give your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to azure team.

Comment: Hi @tom-sun, thanks for the answer. I probably wasn't clear enough in my question (now updated) - I'm looking for a way to receive an OData query and pass this to a CloudTable object, or some other means of passing an OData query via C#. Ideally I don't want to use an HTTP call to pass the OData query. And if the table supports OData queries through HTTP then why doesn't it support the same type of query programmatically?  
Your second link shows programmatic querying of a CloudTable but not using OData. I already know how to query a table using C#; I want to be able to do this using OData.

Comment: Currently, Azure table storage doesn't fully support OData Protocol Specification.Based on my knowledge, it is not supported to use OdataQuery object directly. You could give your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to azure team

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Tom Sun. I have done so: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/33610255-query-tables-using-odataquery-object

Answer (score 2):

If your `OData` query can be expressed with a string, it is possible with the `TableQuery.FilterString` property.

Comment: can you give an example of what you mean please

Comment: The `TableQuery` class in the `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table` namespace has a string property `FilterString` which can be used to assign an OData query such as `Timestamp gt datetime'2018-12-23T20:00:00'`